# How to `serverless upgrade` when receving `Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted`

Tags: upgrade, serverless.com

In the course of trying to upgrade serverless, I received the following error.

```
Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/tmp/serverless-binary-tmp' -> '/home/<username>/.serverless/bin/serverless'
```

Looking into other similar errors/questions on SO, they point out that this error arises when trying to move files across partitions/devices; trouble is that `/tmp` is not a separate partition to `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I first tried looking into changing the `/tmp` folder location for serverless.com, but was unable to find documentation/options to that effect.

Fortunately, a manual copy of the file seems to have been the only missing step

```
cp '/tmp/serverless-binary-tmp' '/home/<username>/.serverless/bin/serverless'
```